# C# how does Console work?

Tags: c#, oop

This is a pretty basic question,

But how does, for example

```
Console.Write("test");
```

work?

Console is a class, not an object.

I'm using console as an example because it is commonly used, but I've seen many examples of using Class.method() instead of object.method().

Comment: That's called a static method. Read about [static members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.90).aspx) and you will understand. I am sure you'll get many good answers here as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That method is called static method: [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

You don't need an instance to call static class member:

> A non-static class can contain static methods, fields, properties, or
>   events. The static member is callable on a class even when no instance
>   of the class has been created. **The static member is always accessed by
>   the class name, not the instance name.** Only one copy of a static
>   member exists, regardless of how many instances of the class are
>   created. Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields
>   and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an
>   instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a
>   method parameter.

Answer (score 2):

`Write` is a static method, so you invoke it on the type instead of on an instance. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hebffx2d.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`Write` is a `static` method in the `Console` class, not an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

Console.Write is a static method which writes to the console without adding a new line.